# Invoke 2 APIs parallely - what is the recommended approach? reactive vs executor?

Tags: java, executorservice, reactive

Have a use case where two services need to be invoked in parallel and then combine the result and return to the caller. (Java, Spring boot based) What are the different approaches possible to achieve this? Threading (Java Executor) or Reactive programming?

The response of 'Service E' can be decided only after getting the response from Service A and Service B.

Caller -> Exposed Service (Service E) -> Service A, Service B

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the best approach but a solution I've used int he past and has worked for me is using comparable futures. Here is an example:

```
    CompletableFuture<ResponseA> futureA
      = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> serviceA.getResponse());
    CompletableFuture<ResponseB> futureB
      = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> serviceB.getResponse());
 
    CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture 
      = CompletableFuture.allOf(futureA, futureB);
 
    // ...
 
    combinedFuture.get();
```

This piece of code will execute both services calls in parallel and it will wait until both calls are finished to exit the get(). After the get you can extract the response from the future variables.